# Replacing a try-catch block with a if condition

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch

For code quality reasons, I would like to replace a `try catch` block inside my code with an `if` condition in order to avoid using a `FrontendException`.

Here is my code :

```
Schema mySchema = new Schema();
mySchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("myInteger", DataType.INTEGER));
mySchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("myBoolean", DataType.BOOLEAN));
Schema tupleSchema = new Schema();
try {
    tupleSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("ARRAY_ELEM", mySchema, DataType.BAG));
} catch (FrontendException e) {
    tupleSchema = new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema(getSchemaName("myClass", input), DataType.DOUBLE));
}
return tupleSchema;
```

Is it possible to replace this code using an `if else` condition? This way I won't have to use this type of Exception and that would be better for SonarQube.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just FWIW, it's "replace with", not "replace by".

Comment: replacing it with an if-else makes no sense. a catch block handles Exceptions that are thrown, an if or else block can't do that.

Comment: A quick observation: The code in the try block looks to be completely deterministic; you should know whether or not it throws an exception.

Comment: And if it does, what does the code in the catch do differently that prevents it from throwing the same exception ?

Comment: But in that case, how to properly catch this `FrontendException` ? Because this Exception handler should provide some context and preserve the original exception but in my case it does not. I should either log or rethrow this exception along with some contextual information, but I do not know how to do.

Comment: If your code snippet is taken from your real code as-is, only two situations are possible: (1) the exception never happens, or (2) the exception always happens. If (1) is the case, replace `try/catch` with the content of `try` block; if (2) is the case, replace  `try/catch` with the content of `catch` block.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm probably missing something, but why does this code always or never throw an exception?

Comment: @biziclop because it is fully self-contained: it takes no arguments, no user input, no random numbers, etc. If you step through it in a debugger, it would always take the same path.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I see it now, yes. Provided, that is, that the `Schema.FieldSchema` constructor is deterministic too.

Answer (score 2):

The exception thrown by the `Schema.FieldSchema` constructor is deterministic. Here is the code of the constructor;

```
public FieldSchema(String a, Schema s, byte t)  throws FrontendException {
        alias = a;
        schema = s;
        log.debug("t: " + t + " Bag: " + DataType.BAG + " tuple: " + DataType.TUPLE);

        if ((null != s) && !(DataType.isSchemaType(t))) {
            int errCode = 1020;
            throw new FrontendException("Only a BAG, TUPLE or MAP can have schemas. Got "
                        + DataType.findTypeName(t), errCode, PigException.INPUT);
        }

        type = t;
        canonicalName = CanonicalNamer.getNewName();
}
```

So the exception is thrown if;

- the Schema given is null
- the DataType given is not a schema type

You know in advance whether the exception will be thrown. In your case it is not so you can safely ignore the exception as *it can never be thrown*. You can remove the code in the catch block. You may as well replace it with;

```
throw new IllegalStateException("Summon Cthulhu");
```

Its a similar case to getting the `UTF-8` charset;

```
String test = "abc";
byte[] bytes;
try {
    bytes = test.getBytes("UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    //Can never happen although the compiler forces us to catch it
}
```

although the method getBytes can throw an exception if the charset is not supported, the `UTF-8` charset is always guaranteed to be supported.